# How to check delay between datasource and processfunction

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

below is the log in my KeyedProcessFunction `processElement`:
`2020-09-16 11:40:54,646 DEBUG com.foo.analysis.FooAnalysis  [] - [4750322][START] pp : (onStreamSeq=4750322, onBackupStreamSeq=null, ppSeq=2450, contextCollectTime=2020-09-16T11:39:50.866null[Asia/Seoul])`

you can see, this element is processed at `2020-09-16 11:40:54,646`
but you can find, the conexteCollectTime is `2020-09-16T11:39:50.866`
there are almost **60** seconds between dataSource and process function.

I wonder how can I find out what caused this long delay?

Comment: Please share your topology (either code or screenshot of Web UI). Do you have any windowing operations?